# creating a field with a count

Tags: count, rows

How can I make a column with a count of records? I want to create something similar to Field1.

```
Field1 Field2
1      apple
1      apple
1      apple
2      orange
2      orange
2      orange
2      orange
```

Comment: Please provide more details? Are you working in Excel? Is this a Text file? Is this a database?

Comment: sorry about that, i'm using oracle sql

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a count of the records.

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM YourTableName;
```

I think you might be asking for a distinct count of Field2. This will give you that.

```
SELECT Count(Distinct Field2) FROM YourTableName;
```

Here is some documentation on count queries. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

And more detail and complex counts with group by. That might be what you are looking for also.

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-use-group-by-with-distinct-aggregates-and-derived-tables

Comment: I tried the statement row_number() over(order by FIELD2) which gave me a column with the numbering of all the rows.  So it gave me:                             Field1                                                                                                                1                                                                                                                2                                                                                                                3  etc.  What is the statement to number all the Field2 records that are identical as 1 & so on?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard, thanks everyone.  I was able to solve my problem using the rank and dense_rank statements